# Automate Email sending, when a Cell value is changed in a Google Spreadsheet with an on Edit trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i want to send an email with an trigger, when a spreadsheet value is changed. So far i watched a lot tutorials and read blogs but i can´t find a solution that works for me.

**The sheet:**

Picture is added

| A    | B      |C      | D     |E       |

| ✖    | 31.03.2021    |Projektnummer 15542      | Vertrag hochladen     |!    |

**The trigger:**

The Trigger is already set on onEdit + send me an email when something is changed

**The code:**

```
function onEdit(e){
  if (e.range.columStart != 5 || e.value != "!") return;
  const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,4).getValues();
  let n = rData[0][2];
  let items = rData[0][3];
  let loc = rData[0][1];
  let now = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");
  
  let msg = n + items + loc + now;
  Logger.log(msg);
  GmailApp.sendEmail("myemail@gmail.com", "Problem!", msg)
}
```

**The Fail Massage:**
TypeError: Cannot read property 'columStart' of undefined

**The Problem:**
I think this code would work, but i get always this failure Message and i can´t see is this code really brings all the 4 rows inside the mail.

Do somebody know a solution?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KoEb.png)

[image]

Comment: Which are the values you are changing manually with the keyboard? I only see formulas in columns A to D.

Answer (score 0):

I thought that your script has 2 modification points.

#### Modification points:

1. Please modify `e.range.columStart` to `e.range.columnStart`.
2. When `onEdit()` is installed as the installable OnEdit trigger, when the cell is edited, `onEdit()` is run 2 times with asynchronous process. One is run as the installable trigger. Another is run as the simple trigger. In your script, when `onEdit()` is run as the simple trigger, an error occurs at `GmailApp.sendEmail()`.

   - So, please rename the function name from `onEdit` to other name and install the renamed function as the installable OnEdit trigger.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function installedOnEdit(e){ // Modified
  if (e.range.columnStart != 5 || e.value != "!") return; // Modified
  const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,4).getValues();
  let n = rData[0][2];
  let items = rData[0][3];
  let loc = rData[0][1];
  let now = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");
  
  let msg = n + items + loc + now;
  Logger.log(msg);
  GmailApp.sendEmail("myemail@gmail.com", "Problem!", msg)
}
```

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Asynchronous Processing using Event Triggers](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/88f7fd5ed14da5e9afde18310da61cb5)

### Added:

From your following replying,

> Hi @Tanaike, i tested it again and it returned the fail massage:"TypeError: Cannot read property 'columnStart' of undefined". Yes you are right, if "!" is in Colum E the script should run. The "!" gets auto populated by an formula. I tried also to put it in manually but then the script also not worked. I read something about, when a formula is triggering an onEdit event, it could be that than the trigger don´t work. but even if i try it to put it in manuelle with no formula it is not working. What do you think? Could it be that my code is not right for this manover? Thank you for your time<3

I understood that you want to run the script when the column "D" is edited and the column "E" is `!`, you want to run the script. For this, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```
function installedOnEdit(e){
  const range = e.range;
  if (range.columnStart != 4 || range.offset(0, 1).getValue() != "!") return;
  const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(range.rowStart,1,1,4).getValues();
  let n = rData[0][2];
  let items = rData[0][3];
  let loc = rData[0][1];
  let now = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");
  
  let msg = n + items + loc + now;
  Logger.log(msg);
  GmailApp.sendEmail("myemail@gmail.com", "Problem!", msg)
}
```

- When you want to run the script, please install the installable OnEdit trigger to the function of `installedOnEdit()` and edit the column "D". When the column "H" of the same edited row is `!`, the script works.

Comment: Dear @Tanakie, first thank you very much for making the effort and helping me! You are really great!!! It is awsome that persons like you helping beginners! 

I tried your code but it sends also an error massage like this:
30.03.21 22:20 installedOnEdit TypeError: Cannot read property 'columnStart' of undefined change 30.03.21 22:20

Do you have a better code solution, probably diffrent from mine? The goal is that  Column A triggers email wich contains Colums B+C+D+E. I think my code is not the best solution after i read your description with the asynchronous processing.

Comment: Oh, i think i found the problem! Is it possible that the scipt not working because i use a formula for that cell that triggers the email sending?

Comment: @Proboto Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current situation from `Oh, i think i found the problem! Is it possible that the scipt not working because i use a formula for that cell that triggers the email sending? `. In order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. When you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, thank you for answering me!!! It´s really kind from you that you want to help me. I thank you for your time!!! Here is a link to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yG7I-fJLyus0TEefnKhtYMamXrEU881DZXsjX7cujmQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: really really nice from you!!! Thank you so much <3

Comment: @Proboto Thank you for replying and providing the sample Spreadsheet. Unfortunately, when I tested your sample script using my modified script, I confirmed that the script worked and the email is sent. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So, can you test it again? By the way, in order to run the script, did you put the value of `!` to the cells "E3:E5" of the column "E"? In your script, I understand that when `!` is put to the column "E", you want to run the script.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, i tested it again and it returned the fail massage:"TypeError: Cannot read property 'columnStart' of undefined". Yes you are right, if "!" is in Colum E the script should run. The "!" gets auto populated by an formula. I tried also to put it in manually but then the script also not worked. I read something about, when a formula is triggering an onEdit event, it could be that than the trigger don´t work. but even if i try it to put it in manuelle with no formula it is not working. What do you think? Could it be that my code is not right for this manover? Thank you for your time<3

Comment: @Proboto Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I understood that you want to run the script when the column "D" is edited and the column "E" is `!`, you want to run the script. For this, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? By the way, unfortunately, I cannot replicate `i tested it again and it returned the fail massage:"TypeError: Cannot read property 'columnStart' of undefined".`. Can I ask you about the detail flow for replicating the issue?